# Hash result of webscraping with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, hash, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape data from multiple urls, hash the result of scraping, compare the hashed result and then notify myself whenever there is a something new posted on a given website. I have managed to successfully hash each individual url, however Im running into issues when comparing hashes. What would be the best approach to this issue? Relevant portion of code provided below:

```
 for i in accounts:
    url_data = requests.get(i)
    url_data = Soup(url_data.content, "html5lib")
    url_data = url_data.find("div", attrs={"class": "results"})
    url_data = str(url_data)
    url_data = html2text.html2text(url_data)

    list_data = list([url_data])

    for l in list_data:
        # print(l)
        url_data = l.encode("utf-8")
        md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
        md5_hash.update(url_data)

        result = md5_hash.hexdigest()

        logger.info(("Start Monitoring... hash "
                    "{url_hash}").format(url_hash=result))

        time.sleep(args.time)

        if(result == result):
            logger.info("Nothing has changed")
            # return False
        else:
            logger.info("Something has changed")
            date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
            print("The Url {l} has changed at {date}.")
            if(not args.nodiff):
                new_result = ""
                new_content = list_data
                s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, new_content)
                for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in s.get_opcodes():
                    if(tag == "insert" or tag == "replaced"):
                        new_result += new_content[j1:j2]
                diff = new_result
                logger.info("{diff}".format(**locals()))
                print(diff)
            # return True

     if __name__ == "__main__":
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument("-t", "--time", help="seconds between 
        checks (default: 600)", default=20, type=int)
        parser.add_argument("-nd", "--nodiff", help="show no 
        difference", action="store_true")

        args = parser.parse_args()

        logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s % 
        (message)s",datefmt="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        scrape_urls()
```

UPDATE

```
class scrape():

def __init__(self, url):
    self.list_data = url
    self.url_hash = self.hash()
    self.get_content = self.scrape_urls()
    logger.info(("Start Monitoring... hash "
                "{url_hash}").format(url_hash=self.url_hash))

def hash(self):
    for l in self.list_data:
        a = hashlib.md5()
        a.update(l.encode("utf-8"))

    return a.hexdigest()

def scrape_urls(self):
    url_data = requests.get(self.list_data)
    url_data = Soup(url_data.content, "html5lib")
    url_data = url_data.find("div", attrs={"class": "results"})
    url_data = str(url_data)
    url_data = html2text.html2text(url_data)

    list_data = list([url_data])

    for l in list_data:

        time.sleep(args.time)

        if(self.hash() == self.url_hash):
            logger.info("Nothing has changed")
            return False
        else:
            logger.info("Something has changed")
            date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y 
            %H:%M:%S")
            print("The Url {l['link ']} has changed at {date}.")
            return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
         parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
         parser.add_argument("-t", "--time", help="seconds between 
         checks (default: 600)", default=5, type=int)


         args = parser.parse_args()

         logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s % . 
         (message)s",datefmt="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
         logger = logging.getLogger()
         logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

         links_list = pd.read_excel('urls_list.xlsx', 
         index=False)
         loc_subset = links_list.to_dict('records')

         accounts = []

         for l in loc_subset:
             url = str(l['link '])

         accounts.append(url)

         for i in accounts:
              print(i)
             url = scrape(i)
             time.sleep(args.time)
             while True:
                  if(url.scrape_urls()):
                         break
                  time.sleep(args.time)
```

Comment: You need to declare another variable. Right now you're evaluating (x == x) which is always true. Try creating something like `previous_result = result` and then compare.

Comment: `list_data` are list of URLs?

Comment: yep thats correct @ewwink

Comment: I have edited the script, however for some reason now I can't iterate over urls which are in the excel doc